# Does orthogonality in Frobenius inner product imply pythagorean orthogonality for spectral norm?

Tags: linear-algebra, inner-products, orthogonality, matrix-norms

We say that matrices are orthogonal (in Frobenius inner product sense) if $\langle A, B \rangle_F = \text{tr}(A^HB) = 0$. Let $A, B$ be traceless matrices in $\mathbb{C}^{4 \times 4}$ that are orthogonal to each other. From this we have

$$
\lVert A + B \rVert_F^{2} = \text{tr}((A+B)^H (A+B)) = tr(A^H A) + tr(A^H B) + tr(B^H A) + tr(B^H B) = \lVert A \rVert^2_F + \lVert B \rVert^2_F
$$
Which is basically a Pythagorean theorem (or Pythagorean orthogonality).

Let $\lVert X \rVert_{2}$ mean spectral or matrix 2-norm which is equal to biggest singular value of $X$.

If traceless matrices in $\mathbb{C}^{4 \times 4}$ $A, B$ are orthogonal (in Frobenius inner product sense) can we say that $\lVert A + B \rVert_2^2 \leq \lVert A \rVert_2^2 + \lVert B \rVert_2^2$?

It is easy to get to
$$
\lVert A + B \rVert_2^2 \leq \lVert A \rVert_2^2 + \lVert B \rVert_2^2 + \max_{\lVert x \rVert_2 = 1}\lVert (A^H B + B^H A)x \rVert_2
$$

But I have hard time going further from here to prove or disprove this statement.

If the statement above is obviously false, then is following true:
$$
\lVert A + B \rVert_2^2 \leq \lVert A \rVert_F^2 + \lVert B \rVert_F^2
$$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The first inequality fails even for diagonal matrices. Indeed, let
$$A=\begin{pmatrix} 1 & 0 & 0 & 0\\
0 & 1 & 0 & 0\\
0 & 0 & -1 & 0\\
0 & 0 & 0 & -1
\end{pmatrix},\quad  B= \begin{pmatrix} 1 & 0 & 0 & 0\\
0 & -1 & 0 & 0\\
0 & 0 & 0 & 0\\
0 & 0 & 0 & 0
\end{pmatrix}$$
Then $\langle A,B\rangle_F =0,$ $\|A\|_2^2=\|B\|_2^2=1$ and $\|A+B\|_2^2=4.$

Concerning the second statement $\|C\|_2\le \|C\|_F$ for any matrix $C.$ Hence
$$\|A+B\|_2^2\le \|A+B\|_F^2=\|A\|_F^2+\|B\|_F^2$$
provided that $\langle A, B\rangle_F =0.$

Comment: In example you have provided, $A$ is not a traceless matrix.

Comment: My bad. I have removed the first part.

Comment: I have modified my first example, extending matrices to $4\times 4. $ In this way it is easier to get the trace equal $0.$

Answer (score 1):

No, the inequality $\|A+B\|_2^2\le\|A\|_2^2+\|B\|_2^2$ is false. Here is a simple counterexample:
$$
A=\pmatrix{-1\\ &-1\\ &&1\\ &&&1},
\ B=\pmatrix{&&&1\\ &&&1\\ &&&1\\ 1&1&1&0},
\ A+B=\pmatrix{-1&&&1\\ &-1&&1\\ &&1&1\\ 1&1&1&1}.
$$
Clearly both $A$ and $B$ are traceless, and they are mutually orthogonal becuase $A$ is a diagonal matrix while $B$ has a zero diagonal. However,
$$
\|A\|_2^2+\|B\|_2^2=1+3=4<5=\dfrac{20}{4}=\dfrac{\|(0,0,2,4)\|_2^2}{\|(1,1,1,1)\|_2^2}=\dfrac{\|e^T(A+B)\|_2^2}{\|e^T\|_2^2}\le\|A+B\|_2^2.
$$